# Is there a way to limit RAM usage by daemon in Debian?

Tags: linux, debian, ulimit, limits

Is there a way to set a limit on the RAM usage (virtual and resident) that a daemon can be granted in Debian? I understand that `ulimit` doesn't apply here, but something the right settings in `/etc/security/limits.conf` may be the answer.

I'm preferably looking for a concrete example. Say, limit virtual to 30MB and resident to 10MB for BIND (whether this is actually a bad idea or not). This setting should be enforced on the RAM used by all processes spawned by that daemon.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can limit the maximum memory used by a program, but if the program want more memory, most of them just abort/crash/whatever.

So you have to configure bind to limit its memory usage.
The main option is `max-cache-size` (look at bind's configuration file, generaly into `/etc/bind/named.conf`). For example `max-cache-size 10M`
Don't use `datasize` if you don't really know what you do.

Answer (score 1):

You wouldn't want to. Virtual memory isn't a scarce resource, so limiting it makes no sense. And limiting a program's resident memory just slows the whole system to a crawl because it makes it need more I/O.